# how to find the interval of convergence.

Tags: power-series

Find the radius and the interval of convergence for the following power series. Justify
your answer!

$\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { (-1)^ k+1(x-1)^ k }{ k3^ k }  } $

**My attempt**

First by using ratio test, I got $-2<x<4$

If x=-2, then $\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { (-1)^ k+1(-3)^ k }{ k3^ k }  } $  = $\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { (-1)^ 2k }{ k }  } $

I am stuck here... can anyone show how to do after substitution and find the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x = -2$, we get 
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k + (-3)^k}{k3^k} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(1 + 3^k)}{k3^k} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k3^k} +  \sum_{k = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k},
$$
which converges by the alternating series test. For the $x = 4$ case, you'll get a non-alternating series,  and won't be able to conclude this.